# MySql Subquerying 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 different tables one is matches, the other is players, I am trying to run a subquery that returns `name` (from `players` table) and `matchno` (from `matches`). I can get it to return one or the other but not both.

Also some of my queries return the error (in workbench 6.0)

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

The irony is killing me =)

My logic on this one is trying to use the normalization, which is `playerno`.

i.e.:

```
select name 
from players
where playerno in 
(select matchno 
from matches
group by matchno)
```

This returns just the name from the players table. I am pretty new to MySql and have scoured my book and internet and am still banging my head against the wall, any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance

I found the query that worked by using a join and a subquery:

```
    select m.matchno, p.name
    from (matches as m inner join players as p
    on m.playerno = p.playerno)
```

Comment: You should only see that error on update queries.  To troubleshoot, run the subquery on it's own so you can see what is being returned.  Decide what row you want and write the necessary code to get it.

Comment: Actually, you would also see that error on select queries if there is an equal sign before the subquery.  If you are using the keyword "in", as per your example, you shouldn't see it.  If you are, edit your question with the specific sql that throws that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to just join the tables in a query. If you have something like this:

```
   players table
id     name
 1      P1
 2      P2

   matches table
idm   idplayer    match
 1       1          blah
 2       1          bleh
 3       2          fly
```

The query to get the matches and players would be

```
 select players.id, 
        players.name, 
        matches.match
   from players, 
        matches 
  where playes.id = matches.idplayer
```

Comment: That seems like it would work, unfortunately this is for a school assignment and the problem specifically states to use a subquery. In real world application I would use the way you susggested.

Comment: Can you provide some example of your data so I can undestand what you are trying to do ?

Comment: the players table contains: PLAYERNO, NAME, INITIALS, BIRTH_DATE, SEX, JOINED, STREET, HOUSENO, POSTCODE, TOWN, PHONENO, LEAGUENO.

Comment: and what is the link with the matches table ?

Comment: sorry ran out of time to edit last comment...the players table contains the columns: PLAYERNO, NAME, INITIALS, BIRTH_DATE, SEX, JOINED, STREET, HOUSENO, POSTCODE, TOWN, PHONENO, LEAGUENO. the matches table contains the columns: MATCHNO, TEAMNO, PLAYERNO, WON LOST. The question asks me to return the values for name and matchno. All the subqueries I run either only return one  of those values or an error. the normalization column is playerno

Comment: select matchno
        from matches
        where playerno in
        (select name
        from players
        where
        (select playerno
        from players 
        where playerno = name))   this is my latest try returns no values, but does not cause an error

Comment: If I undestand it right I can't see an alway to do this unless you put the query that I provide as a subquery and select from it. On your question you where comparing the playerno with matchno which will return just the numbers that match each other. As you say that you need the playerno and the matchno in the result there is no way to do this as you post in your query you either get the player or the match depending on the table you are querying

Comment: Well as your are querying the matches table the appropriate would be: select matchno from matches where playerno in (select playerno from players) but as I said, since your are not querying the table player you cannot have the name

Comment: thats whta i thought as well so there is no way to do this query without a join..thanks for the help